Periodic zeta function
Let $e(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ and let $$F(x,s)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {e(nx)}{n^s}$$ be the periodic zeta function.
What is the functional equation for the periodic zeta function ?: I can find a statement here which says $$
F(x,1-s)=\frac {\Gamma (s)}{(2\pi )^{s}}e(s/4)\zeta (s,x)+\text { similar term }$$
and I can find a statement in Theorem 3.2 of Laurinčikas and Gaurunkštis' book ``The Lerch Zeta Function" which says $$L(\lambda ,\alpha ,1-s)=\frac {\Gamma (s)}{(2\pi )^s}e(s/4-\alpha \lambda )L(-\alpha ,\lambda ,s)+\text { similar term}$$
where $$L(\lambda, \alpha ,s)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac {e(n\lambda )}{(n+\alpha )^s}$$
so in particular $$F(x,1-s)=L(x,1,1-s)=\frac {\Gamma (s)}{(2\pi )^s}e(s/4-\lambda )L(-1,x,s)+\text { similar term}=\frac {\Gamma (s)}{(2\pi )^s}e(s/4-x)\zeta (s,x)+\text { similar term}.$$
So in one statement I have an extra $e(x)$ term. What am I doing wrong?

$\displaystyle\operatorname{F}\left(x,s\right) = \operatorname{Li}_{\Large s}\left({\rm e}^{2\pi{\rm i}x}\right)$.

I'm aware of that but don't see how it resolves my misunderstanding:/
